# Problem with the MathJax rendering of the Hermitian adjoint of an operator $\dagger$ when written as \dag

Tags: bug, status-declined

Normally it is enough just to write `\dag`, i.e. as in `A^{\dag}`, but it doesn't work here:
$$A^{\dag}.$$

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you type `$\newcommand\dag\dagger$` $\newcommand\dag\dagger$ at the beginning of your post, you can type `$$a^\dag$$`$$a^\dag$$ and `$$b^\dag$$`$$b^\dag$$ later. It will work as expected.

I actually use `$\newcommand\ket[1]{\left| #1 \right>}$` quite often in quantum physics related posts, so I can confirm it works.

Comment: genius! IQ good look thought

Comment: Sorry I can't see the trick since I can't edit and latex commands say "\dag" again :O

Comment: @MoreAnonymous  :O I'm ashamed by this enigmatic old post of mine. It should be clearer now, after edit

Comment: It's okay .. I figured this works too \dagger

Comment: Please don't use newcommand in MathJax as this becomes a global setting for all users on the page. Just use the long commands, it's *not* much of a burden to not be lazy.

Comment: @KyleKanos this is [no longer the case](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12798/the-scope-of-newcommand-changed).

Answer (score 8):

Not all LaTeX commands are supported. We use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org) for LaTeX rendering, and the list of macros that are implemented is given on their website. In this case you can use `\dagger` instead.

Comment: The list of macros is here : http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/tex.html#supported-latex-commands